# How to Add Shadow to TableView Without MasksToBound = False

Tags: swift, tableview, shadow, bounds

When I add a shadow to my table view, it only shows if I have `masksToBound = false` as in picture 2. But it will look glitchy. Otherwise it looks fine scrolling up and down as in picture 1 but there's no shadow because I don't set it to false. Changing clipToBounds won't help either. My tableView changes height based on the input into the textField so I think adding a container view might be tricky.

How do I fix this? Is there a simple solution?

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtSearchBar: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tblList: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var shadowView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var tblHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var shadowHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var majors:[String] = Array()

var results: [String] = Array()
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
var originalMajorsList = ["BIO 1AL", "BIO 1B", "BIO 1A", "MCB 118","..."]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = columnLayout
    tblList.delegate = self
    tblList.dataSource = self
    txtSearchBar.delegate = self
    txtSearchBar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchRecords(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)
    txtSearchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground.cgColor
    txtSearchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
    txtSearchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    
    //**glitchy if masksToBounds = false**
    tblList.layer.borderColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground.cgColor
    tblList.layer.borderWidth = 1
    tblList.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    tblList.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    tblList.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -10, height: 10) 
    tblList.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    tblList.layer.shadowRadius = 50
    tblList.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    txtSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
//MARK:- searchRecords
@objc func searchRecords(_ textField: UITextField) {
    tblList.isHidden = false
    self.majors.removeAll()
    if textField.text?.count != 0 {
        for major in originalMajorsList {
            if let majorToSearch = textField.text{
                let range = major.lowercased().range(of: majorToSearch, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)
                if range != nil {
                    self.majors.append(major)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        tblHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    }
    
    tblList.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    tblHeightConstraint.constant = max(0, min(UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.4, tblList.contentSize.height))
}

//MARK:- UITableViewDataSource

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return majors.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "major")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "major")
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = majors[indexPath.row]
    
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if !results.contains(majors[indexPath.row]) {
        results.append(majors[indexPath.row])
    }
    textField.text = ""
    tableView.isHidden = true
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

[image: Normal]

[image: Glitchy]